# How get value of property of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My problem in example below. There I almost build a new array of objects and rename some properties. But there show only the country. Other properties is "undefined".

I tried to do something like this: `name: t.cities[0].id,`

But this method did not iterate over the following objects, only the first

Thanks in advance

```js
let data = [
  {
      "country": "italy",
      "cities": [
          {
              "id": "milan",
              "count": "1366180",              
          },
          {
              "id": "rome",
              "count": "2870500",   
          },
          {
              "id": "torino",
              "count": "870952",   
          }   
      ]
  },
  {
      "country": "france",
      "cities": [
          {
              "id": "paris",
              "count": "2148327",              
          },
          {
              "id": "marseille",
              "count": "869815",   
          },
          {
              "id": "lyon",
              "count": "516092",   
          }   
      ]
  }
]

let rename = data.map( a => ({
  country: a.country,
  cities: data.map( t => ({          
    name: t.cities.id,
    population: t.cities.count,          
  }))
}));

console.log( rename )
```

Comment: It's probably because you're calling `map` _twice_ on the same `data` variable. Instead, you should be accessing the `cities` value from the `a` argument in the callback you passed to the first `data.map`.

Comment: Should be `cities: a.cities.map` not `cities: data.map`

Comment: you are calling `.id` and `.count` on array, not on object. This array don't have those properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner `data.map()` should be `a.cities.map()`. And this map receives the individual city objects, you can access the `id` and `count` properties directly, they don't need to be nested properties.

```js
let data = [
  {
      "country": "italy",
      "cities": [
          {
              "id": "milan",
              "count": "1366180",              
          },
          {
              "id": "rome",
              "count": "2870500",   
          },
          {
              "id": "torino",
              "count": "870952",   
          }   
      ]
  },
  {
      "country": "france",
      "cities": [
          {
              "id": "paris",
              "count": "2148327",              
          },
          {
              "id": "marseille",
              "count": "869815",   
          },
          {
              "id": "lyon",
              "count": "516092",   
          }   
      ]
  }
]

let rename = data.map( a => ({
  country: a.country,
  cities: a.cities.map( city => ({          
    name: city.id,
    population: city.count,          
  }))
}));

console.log( rename )
```